# What is the SQL standard for updating one row when multiple are matched with an UPDATE+FROM

Tags: sql, join, sql-update

With the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
 id int primary key, 
 local_id int not null
);

INSERT INTO tableA (id,local_id) VALUES
(122,0),(123,0),(124,0);

UPDATE tableA SET tableA.local_id = tableB.id
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS rn
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS id, 1 AS rn
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS id, 1 AS rn
) AS tableB
WHERE tableA.id = 123 AND tableB.rn = 1;
```

This SQL matches only 1 row in `tableA` and 3 rows in `tableB`.

What is the rule for updating `local_id` in this case? without an `ORDER BY` inside the inner `FROM`, it seems that it picks the highest `INT`, but I doubt that behavior is explicit? (In this case it is 3).

Is this behavior defined somewhere in the SQL standard?
If I set `ORDER BY id DESC` inside the parenthesis, am I certain it will always pick the top row?

This is a simplified problem, usually, more than 1 row is updated in `tableA`, so setting a `TOP/LIMIT` is not going to cut it.

Comment: We don't know `tablea` and we don't know what result you expect. So [edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables and/or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. `UPDATE`s with joins are often vendor specific, so tag the DBMS you're using and its version.

Comment: So this question is more about how postgresql decides which value to pick. I think it's random, but with higher probability for the first on the stack. Hence, order descending and it's more probably the highest value.  Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a06c49a497a8ec9f16a5ddbbb690f703)*

Comment: @LukStorms I appreciate the fiddle, I have updated the question. This happens also in MSSQL. So there must be a rule or a standard somewhere.

Comment: Well, in standard SQL a FROM isn't allowed to begin with in an UPDATE statement. So the SQL standard has nothing to say about this as it simply is invalid (standard) SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If it's not a standard, it would be interesting to know if this behavior is defined somewhere. Can I guarantee that if I use the `ORDER BY` inside the inner to work as expected aka pick the top row? If there is nothing defined about this, then it's basically playing with fire.

Answer (score 0):

Current query give just an error. You can update multiple rows with 1 value from target table. But you can't update 1 row with multiple values from target. So just make target table unique. As you mentioned, get max value.